# How do you delete files before they have been uploaded by the dojo Multifile Uploader?

Tags: dojo, multifile-uploader

I am using a dojox.form.uploader.FileList here: https://github.com/chotchki/pgGallery/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/gallery/gallery.jsp#L129

I have looked through the API documentation and can't find a way to allow the user to remove a file from the list to be uploaded before they click upload.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found no solution too, so i wrote this little hack, it just extending dojox/form/Uploader. So far it seems to work for me, at least in Firefox. It adds a method removeFile(index) and a onRemove(file) method to the Uploader class.

What you need to do is use force="iframe" on your uploader Element or set the property on your object.

```
require(["dojo/_base/lang","dojox/form/Uploader","dojo/dom-construct","dojo/_base/array"],function(lang, Uploader, domConstruct, array){
    lang.extend(Uploader,{
        removeFile: function(index){
            if(this._inputs.length > index){

                //Delete input field from dom
                domConstruct.destroy(this._inputs[index]);

                //Delete file From input Array
                var _arr = new Array();
                var _file = this._inputs[index];
                array.forEach(this._inputs,function(n,i){
                    if(i != index){
                        _arr.push(n);
                    }
                });
                this._inputs = _arr;
                this.onRemove(_file);
            }

        },
        onRemove: function(file){

        }
    });
 });
```